# Word or phrase, containing another word or phrase that sounds exactly alike

Tags: terminology, literary-techniques

I've been searching for this literary concept for two days straight, with no luck. So bear with me please as I explain. I'm looking for the correct term to use when wordplay is used in a way that's related to pronunciation. So, what is it called when you say a word, but if you were to listen to it again (exactly the same way) it could sound like a whole new phrase / concept?

**Example 1 : Beyonce's song "in formation"**

She sings it saying, "OK ladies now let's get '*in formation*'," or one could have heard her say, "OK ladies now lets get '*information*'." One could have heard it either way. One way with one full word in itself with no spaces, or another way with a phrase that requires spaces. The trick is both ways sound exactly alike.

**Example 2 : the word "queso"**

It could be said as "*queso*" as in the melted cheese, or "K, so?" as in the sarcastic gesture many of us use sometimes. (Another way they both sound the same but can mean two different things.)

**Example 3 : "Lettuce Leave"** 

"Lettuce Leave" simply means a single leaf from a salad or such, or one could use it as a command in a group setting: "Let us leave!"

Comment: Phonetic pun, sound pun, homophonic pun.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [***pun***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pun), also called *paronomasia*.

> The pun is a form of word play that suggests two or more meanings, by exploiting multiple meanings of words, or of similar-sounding words, for an intended humorous or rhetorical effect.
> These ambiguities can arise from the intentional use of homophonic, homographic, metonymic, or figurative language.

References:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pun
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_of_speech (list)